# What size textures do I need for a 2D grid based game if my tiles are larger than textures I have?

Tags: 2d, textures, sprites, tiles, grid

I'm building a grid-based game for iPad, and for usability purposes I've selected my game grid to be built of 75x75 squares. However, so far I've seen that the majority of (free)texture catalogs I can find are either 16x16 or 32x32.

Currently I have the graphics engine stretch the 32x32 texture onto a 75x75 tile, which does not look very sharp.

How can I make my game look good -  **do I need to create textures whose size is equal to my game tile?** Should I try to stitch multiple textures together (like 4 texture squares per game square)?

Comment: How critical is the 75px grid? Do you have any room to approximate? eg. If you glued-together four 32x32 tiles to make a 64x64 meta-tile, would that be close enough to your desired scale for usability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have to create images at the desired resolution.

Whether you should stitch textures together can not be answered. It depends on what textures you use and what the result looks like, nothing else. Alternatively reduce the grid size.

Comment: seems pretty obvious to me

Comment: yeah, I was afraid this is a case. Either a lot of work for me, or money to pay for freelance work :/